# How do i get the game object to follow another game object but not move into the targeted object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how do i get the game object to follow another game object where it will be dragged in the scene but not move into the targeted object? The game object that i want to follow the targeted game object needs to be on top of the targeted game object.

Heres my current code.

```
public float speed;
public GameObject targetObject;
public Transform myGameObject;


void Update()
{
    myGameObject.transform.position = 
    Vector3.MoveTowards(myGameObject.transform.position,  
    targetObject.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the position of `targetObject` and get the `distance` between the two.  So, you would check if `myGameObject` is within a certain radius of `targetObject`, and if it is not move it towards the position of `targetObject`.

Your code might look something like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Vector3.Distance(myGameObject.transform.position, targetObject.transform.position) >= minimumDistance) {
        myGameObject.transform.position = 
            Vector3.MoveTowards(myGameObject.transform.position,  
            targetObject.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

Where `minimumDistance` is the radius in which you don't want `myGameObject` to move anymore.

---

Also, you might want to move it to the position above `targetObject` instead of towards the middle of it.  This way, you would do something like this:

```
void Update()
{
    myGameObject.transform.position = 
        Vector3.MoveTowards(myGameObject.transform.position,  
        targetObject.transform.position + new Vector3(0, up, 0), Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

Where `up` is how far above the center of `targetObject` you need the object to be.

Hope this helped!